# UILabel not showing up in the view

Tags: swift, autolayout

**Problem**

I'm trying to fully understand building a Swift app entirely programmatically but I'm getting hung up on layout anchors. I have a tableview and if a row is selected it will push a new viewcontroller into the view.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as! CoinCell
    if let coin = currentCell.coin {
        let newViewController = CoinViewController(coin)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
    }
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

Below is my code for the viewcontroller that is being pushed. I'm able to see that the nameLabel has text while debugging but I can't seem to have the labels actually show in the view.

```
var coin: Coin? {
    didSet {
        nameLabel.text = coin?.name
    }
}

init(_ coin: Coin) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.coin = coin
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    view.addSubview(nameLabel)
    view.addSubview(testLabel)
    setupView()
}

let nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

let testLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.text = "TEST"
    return label
}()


func setupView() {
    nameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    nameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    nameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    nameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
}
```

I'm still a beginner with this so I'm not sure of the best way to actually debug an issue like this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why constrain the label's width and height? Does the text show up if you remove those 2 constraints?

Comment: It doesn't, I already tried removing that. I think there might just be an issue with how I'm setting the nameLabel actually

Comment: set background color for labels and see did they appear on screen or not ?

Comment: I added the same left and top anchor constraints to my testLabel and it appeared. I'm almost positive that my nameLabel just isn't getting data correctly now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are precisely making sure that your controller receive data (or non optional data) via the `initializer`, you should replace the `property observer` (didSet) to just a simple property.

```
let coin: Coin 

init(_ coin: Coin) { 
    self.coin = coin 
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
 }
// now in viewDidLoad() you can set the text of your label i.e namelabel.text = self.coin.something
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to set the text `nameLabel` in the property observer:

```
var coin: Coin? {
    didSet {
        nameLabel.text = coin?.name
   }
}
```

But `didSet` will *not* be called from the initializer, therfore the label will remain empty.

In iOS (Cocoa Touch), you should fill your views after/within `viewDidLoad` (or `viewDidAppear`) or - in your case - in `setupView`:

```
func setupView() {
    nameLabel.text = coin?.name
    // ...
}
```